# Troubles with arangodb graph viewer

Tags: graph, arangodb

In graph viewer, is it possible to not start with a random vertice? When I uncheck the option, the graph simply disappears. But I don't get to choose the starting point anywhere.

And when I set up the configuration it is not saved to the graph view. Is this going to be fixed? I find it kind of a key feature for a graph-database to be able to easily explore the graph.

I am working with arrangodb 2.3.1

Anyway, besides some trouble with the graph viewer, I really enjoy this fancy multi model database! And for me it is a big plus it's made in Germany! Keep on the great work arangodb-team!

Comment: You can select another start vertex later in the graph viewer: First, click on the filter icon and then use the two input boxes that will show up. Enter `_key` into the left box and a known key of a vertex into the other box and press return. This should bring up the vertex with the given `_key` value. You can also use other attributes if you don't want to select a vertex using its `_key`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you can select the start vertex later.

1. Click on the Filter icon (see image)
2. Two input boxes should appear - `Attribute name` and `Attribute value`. Type in `_key` into the left box (see image)
3. Type in a known `_key` of a vertex (or another attribute) into the right box (see image)
4. Simply hit return and you should see the vertex with the given `_key` value

[image: Graph Viewer]

Comment: OK, this solved first part of my question. Thank you! What about saving the configs (and filters) to the graph view? I have to reset the filter and enable 'undirected graph' each time I reopen the graph.

Comment: Sadly I think there is no way to save the configs at the moment. This is a feature that we will work on.